# How to know when all images inside a specific "div" are loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

Part of my HTML page is the following `div`:

```
<div id="images_wrapper">
  <img ... />
  <img ... />
  <img ... />
  ...
</div>
```

Initially, this `div` is hidden, and I show it only when all images are loaded:

```
$(window).load(show_images_wrapper);
```

However, if I'm not mistaken, `show_images_wrapper` will be called only when all the page is loaded. I would like `show_images_wrapper` to be called as soon as all images inside `images_wrapper` has been loaded, and don't wait until all the page is loaded.

I tried:

```
$("#images_wrapper").load(show_images_wrapper);
```

but it didn't work.

How should I do this?

Comment: I would check and see that the images are actually loaded by your browser when they are hidden. I have a suspicion that the images aren't downloaded to the browser you're using until they are actually rendered, but I could be wrong. You can determine this using firebug, chrome developer tools, or IE developer tools in the networking tabs.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Set up a counter to the quantity of the images using the [`length`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property, that is decremented as the images load.

```
var imgs = $("#images_wrapper > img").not(function() { return this.complete; });
var count = imgs.length;

if (count) {
    imgs.load(function() {
        count--;
        if (!count) {
            $("#images_wrapper").show();
            alert('all done');
        }
    });
} else {
    $("#images_wrapper").show();
}
```

The the [`not()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method is removing from the matched set the images where their `.complete` property is `true`. This means the image has already downloaded, and was perhaps cached by bhe browser.

Of course the [`load()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) method fires as each image finishes loading.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/uhmAR/1/

---

**EDIT:** Changed it so that the container will show if *all* the images happened to be cached.

---

**EDIT:**

Another variation on the above is to bind the `.load()` to all the images, and use the [`filter()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to get the ones that are `.complete`, and just manually invoke the `.load()` on them.

This removes the need for the `if/else` statement.

```
var imgs = $("#images_wrapper > img")
var count = imgs.length;

imgs.load(function() {
    count--;
    if (!count) {
        $("#images_wrapper").show();
        alert('all done');
    }
}).filter(function() { return this.complete; }).load();
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/uhmAR/3/

Comment: @Jared: Hey, I take 'em when I can get 'em!  ;o)

Comment: @patrick I've seen `complete` property before, do you have any recommended reading?

Comment: @alex: Honestly, I've never found much documentation on it. I found something at MDC once, but now I can't locate it. To my knowledge, it has full browser support though (including IE6).

Comment: here the official documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/complete

Answer (score 11):

I wrote a [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) that can do this.

```
$('#images_wrapper').waitForImages(function() {
   // Done.
});
```

Alternatively,

```
var images = $('#images_wrapper img'),
    imagesLength = images.length;

images.load(function() { 

    if ( ! --imagesLength) {
        // Done.
    }

});
```

Comment: @Misha What part specifically do you mean by his method? The code is available on the link if you want to inspect it yourself.