# Check if image loaded before jquery plugin starts

Tags: jquery, image, load

For e.g I have a imageslider plugin.

```
<div class="images">
    <img src="1.jpg"/>
    <img src="2.jpg"/>
    .... 
</div>
$('.images').slider();
```

How can I specify in the plugin(any skeleton) that I want to start the plugin only when all images are loaded? Is it like e.g using a .load() method and adding to a variable everytime an image has loaded. Then once it reaches total number of images, call the plugin? But how can I 'pause' the plugin?

Thanks everyone, but I did mention IN a skeleton jquery plugin itself, how would i call the plugin after the images have loaded?

Answer (score 6):

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.images').slider();
});
```

`$(window).load` will wait until all images are loaded on the page.

If you need to know when the images have finished loading in that particular div, please see the answers in this question: [How to know when all images inside a specific "div" are loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488104/how-to-know-when-all-images-inside-a-specific-div-are-loaded)

Comment: This will wait for *all* the images on the page. The OP wants to know when the images inside of `.images` have loaded.

Comment: Thanks but is there no way i can specify this in the plugin?

Comment: I am not familiar with this particular plugin. Take a look at their documentation.

Comment: Vibhu what I meant was, with a skeleton plugin generated, how would I call the plugin when the images are loaded?

Comment: I think you should ask this question again in a different way.

Comment: I did mention that I need it to be in the plugin

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the plugin on the [`window.load` event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) like so:

```
$(window).load(function () {
  $('.images').slider();
});
```

This is as opposed to the much more commonly used `document.ready` event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.images').slider();
});
```

The key difference is that the latter will execute when the DOM is finished loading, while the former will wait until all resources referenced by the DOM are loaded.  Note that if another resource is taking a long time to load even after the images are ready, then it will hold up the plugin until it loads or times out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this which will initialize the plugin after all the images are loaded.

```
$(function(){
   var imageCount = $(".images img").length;
   $(".images img").load(function(){
       imageCount--;
       if(imageCount == 0){
          $(this).parent().slider();
       }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To check for all the images in just that element is a little tricky, but can be done.

```
//gather the total number of images
var imageNum = $('.images').find('img').length;
var imagesLoaded = 0;
//setup a load event for each img
$('.images img').each(function(){
    //load event will fire inconsistently in IE/FF so we create a new dom element but don't insert it
    $('<img>').load(function(){
        imagesLoaded++;
        //all images are loaded so fire the slider
        if(imagesLoaded == imageNum){
            $('.images').slider();
        }
    //we set the new img to have the src of the current image
    }).attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

It's a little clunky, but should work.